# IllegalStateException: "Undefined label used" with ASM > 4.1

Tags: java, illegalstateexception, java-bytecode-asm

I want to upgrade Commons Javaflow from ASM 4 to 5 (same problem with 4.1 ) and I get this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Undefined label used
at org.objectweb.asm.util.CheckMethodAdapter.visitMaxs(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.commons.javaflow.bytecode.transformation.asm.ContinuationMethodAdapter.visitMaxs    (ContinuationMethodAdapter.java:313)
at org.objectweb.asm.tree.MethodNode.accept(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.commons.javaflow.bytecode.transformation.asm.ContinuationMethodAnalyzer.visitEnd(ContinuationMethodAnalyzer.java:140)
```

the code triggering this error is:

```
   public void visitMaxs(int maxStack, int maxLocals) {
      Label endLabel = new Label();
      mv.visitLabel(endLabel);

      mv.visitLocalVariable("__stackRecorder", "L" + STACK_RECORDER + ";", null, startLabel, endLabel, stackRecorderVar);

      mv.visitMaxs(0, 0);
  }
```

Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Is [this bug report](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SANDBOX-476) yours? I don’t think that stackoverflow is a place where you find more information than apache and objectweb devs can give you.

Comment: Yes, I created the issue there after.

Comment: A fix has been added to the issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SANDBOX-476